# Using Sliding Fragment to Display Data Instead of ListView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-sliding

I was displaying data retrieved from my database in `listView`.

Now I want to display  them in sliding `Fragment` like as you see in the following pictures.

[My listView is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGyMl.png).

[How I want now to display it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYxx7.png).

Answer (score 0):

Ok what you need to use is a `ViewPager` which will display your content as pages the view that you want, and it will enable you to swipe between them.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) is an easy guide to get you started. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you.But I was looking for a tuto with cursor and viewpager because as i say i have data.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your CursorAdapter in a PagerAdapter to get the functionality of both. It should look something like this, although I haven't tested this code closely:

```
public class CursorPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private CursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

    public CursorPagerAdapter(CursorAdapter cursorAdapter) {
        mCursorAdapter = cursorAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCursorAdapter.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = mCursorAdapter.getView(position, null, container);
        mCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);
        mCursorAdapter.bindView(view, container.getContext(), mCursorAdapter.getCursor());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

}
```